# Hedera Minting DAPP, How to connect wallet

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

Im coming from the 'other' blockchains and not sure how we would authenticate a Hedera user on a DAPP. Essentially I need to create a minting DAPP.
I need the user to connect his wallet, pay using HBAR and get his token.
Do I need to use a wallet provider like hashpack or something?

Answer (score 2):

Today there are limited, mostly custodial design options available. This is subject to change with [HIP-179 External Transaction Signing for SDK and other clients](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-179).

Prior to HIP-179, most applications are either:

1. Using a single managed custodial account on their web server.
2. Tying a traditional login(email, password) or session to an application-specific generated Hedera account.
3. Asking users for keys as a login.
4. Involving some counterparty risk wherein a transaction is sent from a 3rd party wallet (e.g. sending hbar) and a promise to send a token, etc. back.

There are obvious security and scam concerns with most of these models. Once HIP-179 is in place it will be easier for extensions like HashPack and others to sign transactions.

Comment: Any other source??